# I am passing float value to function square but the value getting printed is 0

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

float square(float);

main()
{
    float a,b;
    printf("enter the number=");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    b=square(a);
    printf("the square is=%d",b);
}

float square(float x)
{
    float y;
    y=x*x;
    return(y);
}
```

Comment: "%d" is for int

Comment: `%d` is for printing ints, not floats. Use the correct conversion specifier.

Comment: What value has the variable `a` after `scanf` when you run the code in the debugger?

Comment: Are we still accepting endless questions about blatantly wrong format specifiers?

Comment: BTW: unrelated to your question but you should write `return y;` instead of `return(y);`. Latter is not wrong, but just unusual.

Comment: @iBug I wish not.  It's an obvious error, but typically appears at the end of posted code,.and so wastes the maximum amout of user's time:(

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

needs to be

```
scanf("%f",&a);
```

`%d` is meant for reading `int`s while `%f` is meant for reading `float`s.

If you increase the warning level on your compiler you might be able to detect that as a problem at compile time. For example, using `gcc -Wall`, I get the following output:

```
soc.c:5:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^
soc.c: In function ‘main’:
soc.c:9:11: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d",&a);
           ^
soc.c:11:12: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("the square is=%d",b);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with float numbers, you have to use `"%f"` specifier in `printf` and `scanf` calls. Now you have `"%d"`, but this is for integer values (you can read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printfspecifier) about this).

So, try this:

```
...
scanf("%f", &a);
b=square(a);
printf("the square is=%f", b);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In your scanf and printf in main function use %f instead of %d

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier for a float is "%f" while "%d" is used in case of an integer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

float square(float);

main() {
  float a,b;
  printf("Enter the number=");
  scanf("%f",&a);
  b=square(a);
  printf("The square is=%f",b); 
}

float square(float x) {
  float y;
  y=x*x;
  return(y); 
}
```

This code should work.
Although I would suggest you use integers as the code would show decimal points with the square output.

```
Enter the number=2
The square is=4.000000
```